# How to run Mongodb Docker image pulled from docker hub running in OpenShift

Tags: mongodb, docker, openshift

I need to deploy an application on openshift which is highly dependent on MongoDB to bring the main API pod. The constraint over here is the MongoDB image used in the deployment requires to run as root but openshift doesn't allow that. Is there a walk around this?

I have already tried the solution mentioned under this link 
https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/17164

Deployment.yaml

```
- apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    name: mongo
    namespace: default
  spec:
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: mongo
        role: master
        tier: backend
    replicas: 1
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: mongo
          role: master
          tier: backend
      spec:
        initContainers:
          - name: config-data-path
            image: busybox
            command: 
              - /bin/chmod
              - -R
              - "777"
              - /data/db
            volumeMounts:
              - name:  data
                mountPath: /data/db
        containers:
          - name: mongo
            image: mongo
            ports:
              - containerPort: 27017
            volumeMounts:
              - name: data
                mountPath: /data/db
        volumes:
          - name: data
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: mongo-pv-claim
```

Error log from the container.

```
chmod: /data/db: Permission denied
chmod: /data/db: Permission denied
```

Comment: See https://cookbook.openshift.org/users-and-role-based-access-control/how-can-i-enable-an-image-to-run-as-a-set-user-id.html

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I followed the cookbook, but still the pod ends up **Error** status on getting the logs they say **find: '/data/db': Permission denied**
**chown: changing ownership of '/data/db': Permission denied**

Comment: What sort of OpenShift cluster are you trying to use? If using Minishift (on macOS at least), have seen that it doesn't really like having a pod run as `root` and trying to use a persistent volume. BTW, any reason you aren't using the mongodb image/template that comes with OpenShift and has been designed to run as non `root`?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I am using managed openshift service on IBM Cloud and I haven't tried to use the MongoDB image that comes with Openshift. Let me try If work I will let you know.